# Track Facebook ad traffic to page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a Facebook Page Tab which is being promoted with various Facebook Ads (via the Destination Tab option).

Inside the Page Tab there's a button. How can I know on the client-side which specific ad sent the user to the Page Tab when the button is clicked?

Comment: Let me know if you found the answer because I'm looking at this now. (1 app for 3 series of creative).

Comment: Hmmm still no answer. Facebook Marketing Team can't tell me how to track down clicks form ad to pagetab too.